# Java - Refresh database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot MVC with Java.

And I have this EndPoint:

```
@GetMapping("/validate/{idIntRaptMec}")
public ResponseEntity<?> validate(@PathVariable(value="idIntRaptMec") Long idIntRaptMec ){

      //Get the appointment from the table    
      IntRaptMec appointment = intRaptMecService.getPointment(idIntRaptMec);
      (...)
}
```

When I use the 'getPointment(idIntRaptMec)' it recovers an object from the database via JPA. Everything runs OK until here.

But, it seems like the object that this method recovers it's Out of date.

Some of its properties are NULL, but the record of this object in the database is populated including the properties that the java says to be null.

I think that I must use some type of "RefreshDatabase" method. I don't know if really exists, but I'm felling that Java Spring Boot it's using a "cached database". Is this true? Is there a way to fix this?

I can't put the IntRaptMec model class here because it's too big (About 40+ properties). I did not create it this table. But I can show to you some of properties that are returning NULL but are filled in the database:

```
@Column(name="CD_EQUIPTO")
 public Long getCdEquipto() {
            return this.cdEquipto;
 }

 public void setCdEquipto(Long cdEquipto) {
        this.cdEquipto = cdEquipto;
 }

 @Column(name="CD_OPERACAO")
 public BigDecimal getCdOperacao() {
    return this.cdOperacao;
 }
 public void setCdOperacao(BigDecimal cdOperacao) {
    this.cdOperacao = cdOperacao;
 }

 @Column(name="CD_UPNIVEL3")
 public String getCdUpnivel3() {
    return this.cdUpnivel3;
 }

 public void setCdUpnivel3(String cdUpnivel3) {
    this.cdUpnivel3 = cdUpnivel3;
 }
```

I'm not working with transactions. The connection with database it's correct because I can get other objects (from other Models) without problem. I'm using a Oracle Database.

This is the intRaptMecService class:

```
@Service
public class IntRaptMecService {

    @Autowired
    IntRaptMecRepository intRaptMecRepository; 

    public IntRaptMec getPointment(Long id) {

            Optional<IntRaptMec> obj = intRaptMecRepository.findById(id);
            return obj.get();

    }
}
```

This is the IntRaptMecRepository class:

```
@Repository    
public interface IntRaptMecRepository extends JpaRepository<IntRaptMec, Long>{

}
```

[image: This is the object that I want to get from the Database]

Comment: What JPA provide do you use? Do you see outdated object in your browser or using breakpoint in your IDE?

Comment: Are the null properties lazy loaded? Please show your persistent class and the mapping.

Comment: *I must use some type of "RefreshDatabase" method*: no. *Spring Boot it's using a "cached database". Is this true?* no. *Is there a way to fix this?*: yes, probably by fixing the code that you're not showing us. Or by connecting to the right database. Or by committing the changes you've made to the database.

Comment: @Ivan I see the outdated object using breakpoint with IDE.

Comment: I added more information to the post question

Comment: Have you committed the changes made to the database?

Comment: I asked to my supervisor. He told that after using any UPDATE in the database I must use the command "COMMIT" when using Oracle database. I used it and the changes commited and now the object its returning correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

If you are using an Oracle database, after you perform any update on your database table you must use the `COMMIT;` statement to save the changes that you made.

After using the commit, the object returned correctly.

Comment: That should be something hibernate handles for you.. If you're using it to save the data.

Comment: You need to commit your data with any database (except maybe MySQL when using MyISAM tables).

Comment: @XtremeBiker I would guess that these changes were made externally, eg using SQL Developer or another query tool. And not through the Hibernate-based application.

Comment: I used SQL Developer to do an update. That's why I got this inconsistency.